# How to transfer a question with its coments from Beta to Chat

Tags: discussion, chat

I have encountered many instances of a question being transferred from History to chat, along with all its comments. ([This question in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51417/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-sakib-arifin-were-6-million-jews-killed-in-co) is one of the most recent.) I've tried to do this myself, but it doesn't work. Could you give me instructions or a link with instructions telling me how to transfer a question plus its comments to chat?

Comment: The only way I know to do it as a user is to wait for the "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" message to come up and click the link. As a mod, we have the ability to access a "move comments to chat" link from the mod menu.

Comment: You can always create a chatroom yourself and paste a link to the question in it though. Then you can provide a link to the chatroom in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only moderators can do this, generally.

However, if you chat back and forth with one user long enough it eventually prompts you to take it to chat.